# Virtualbox - Tails - failed to open disk image file

Tags: virtualbox

Host machine: OSX Mojave

Virtualbox: 6.0.4

Tails: 3.12

Where I download virtualbox: `brew cask install virtualbox`. NOTE: I had virutalbox installed quite awhile and using it with `vagrant` and `ansible` to test playbook and stuff, and did make sure everything was clean when trying to run tails.

Where I download the image file: [from tails site download using torrent](https://tails.boum.org/install/download-iso/index.en.html)

How I attempted to run tails from ISO image in virtual box: [steps follow from tails documentation](https://tails.boum.org/doc/advanced_topics/virtualization/virtualbox/index.en.html), it was straightforward and tried it more than five times

Error occurred at: **steps 7**, from the tails doc at configuring virtual machine to start from an ISO image, and below are the detail error:

```
The medium '/my-path/tails-amd64-3.12.iso'
can't be used as the requested device type.


Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MediumWrap
Interface: IMedium {ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1}
Callee: IVirtualBox {d0a0163f-e254-4e5b-a1f2-011cf991c38d}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

Expectation: No error popup at steps 7, which at the adding tails ISO image, and the rest of the step and could successfully start tails up

Attemps to get it work:

**Attempt one:** I watched one video from youtube that was about 7 months ago running tails in virtualbox, the process was pretty straightforward but I still get the same error.

**Attemp two:** I googled about the issue and only found simliar error. Those are conflicting Disk ID, which I applied the solution but got no luck.

I don't really use virtualbox much so are there anyway I can know more about the error message or anyone knows how to do with this? Thanks beforehand and appreciate for your precious time and help.

Answer (score 0):

It is working now, the weird thing is that I have to directly open the .iso image instead of clicking on the folder that contains the .iso.